# Assigning a variable to an index of a 2d array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign a variable to an index of a 2d array, and then with this variable I will move it around the 2d array. For example, `let p = grid[0][0]`, I would then want to be able to move it to `grid[1][0]`, `grid[1][5]`, etc. But I'm being returned with an undefined variable value with the code below:

```
const intiateGrid = (x) => {

    grid = new Array(x);

    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(x);
    }

    return grid; 
}

let grid = []
intiateGrid(10);

let p = grid[0][0];

console.log(p);
```

Comment: for starters you never assign the result of `intiateGrid(10)` to grid. should be `let grid = intiateGrid(10)`

Comment: You're getting `undefined` because your code creates the structure, but nothing populates the arrays with values. The result of `new Array(x)` is an array filled with `x` undefined values.

Comment: `grid` in the scope of *initiateGrid* is not the same `grid` in global

Comment: @Fallenreaper what makes you think that? The only declaration for `grid` is outside the function.

Comment: @Smytt because `grid` is declared outside the function, it really doesn't matter. (I would not write the code that way, but it should work.)

Comment: @Pointy you can define a variable without var or let, or at least in console windows.  I would think that it may know what grid is, but beyond the scope it will reset to its previous value

Comment: The description of what you want to do with `p` sounds a lot like something that doesn't make sense. The value of `p` will be the copy of an array element value. You can't create a single value that can be used as a reference into a 2-dimensional array structure.

Comment: @Fallenreaper no, the `let` declaration will be hoisted to the top of the code block, and that's what `grid` will be inside the function. Because there actually is a declaration, it will not be an implicit global declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you never assign the result of `intiateGrid(10)` to grid. Should be `let grid = intiateGrid(10)`. There are more issues with the code as well, but let me know more about it. For example should `intiateGrid(number)` create a square matrix? What should the initial values be? Also, don't mutate the matrix while you loop through it.

```js
const grid = intiateGrid(10);

const player = {
  rowIndex: 0,
  colIndex: 0
}

//player starts at [0][0]
movePlayer(0, 0)

function intiateGrid(x) {
  const arr = new Array(x).fill(0); // array with x zeros
  const grid = arr.map(element => new Array(x).fill('O')) // array with x arrays, each with x zeros.
  return grid;
}

function movePlayer(row, col) {
  grid[row][col] = 'P';

  //set -1 to previous location
  grid[player.rowIndex][player.colIndex] = 'X'

  //update player location
  player.rowIndex = row;
  player.colIndex = col;

  console.log(`Player is at [${player.rowIndex}][${player.colIndex}]`)
}

movePlayer(1,0);
movePlayer(1,1);
movePlayer(1,2);
movePlayer(1,3);
movePlayer(2,3);

grid.forEach(row => console.log(row.join(' | ')))
```

Comment: Hey, I will let you know more about. It is supposed to create a square matrix. To me the initial values aren't important. The reason for this is that there is going to be a starting postion at `0,0` - this may need a valye, and various obstacles in the grid - which may also need values. Then depending on user input, the starting position will change by either incremeting 1 across the x axis and incrementing 1 on the y axis - hope that makes sense

Comment: so, the position where the "player" is is for example 1 and everything else - 0? so if I move right [0][1] becomes 1 and [0][0] becomes 0? is that it?

Comment: Not quite, let's give player the a value of 'player' and begins at an index of [0][0]. Say I want to move `player` to the index [1][0], my logic is to then increment the first index by 1 and move the player to that index

Comment: I think you're not quite clear yourself on what you need done. what do you mean by "move the player"? the way to store information on where the player is is to put some value that you know in the matrix. Otherwise the matrix is uselsess. You can simply keep a string like `position = '34'` which would mean row index 3, column index 4. If you have the matrix, keep values in it - for example - the player can be 1, the obstacle can be 2 and the empty cells can be 0. Visited cells can be -1 or something. It would be helpful to provide the matrix after each player move - what it should look like.

Comment: ok, I edited the code. Now O means "empty spot", "X" means visited and "P" is our player.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is to create:

```
[ [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ],
  [ <10 empty items> ] ]
```

You are assigning p to be the first empty item in the first array. So of course console.log() will print undefined because you haven't assigned any value yet. And as others pointed out already you didn't assign the value of your function anywhere so the assignment of `grid[0][0]` would point to nothing anyway.

You need to assign them either via `grid[0][0] = 0;` or initialize all indices  together with `fill(number);`

@Smytt solution is definitely cleaner and avoids the pitfalls of your solution. With your current solution every function call would change the maybe already modified grid. At the same time the function is not applicable to any other grids you might want to create without overwriting the current since it can only modify grid. You can remove the `let grid = [];` and `console.log(grid);` would still show you the array as seen at the top of my post. You are working with side effects that are stated only implicitly which is considered a dangerous style.

```js
const intiateGrid = (x) => {

    grid = new Array(x);

    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(x);
    }

    return grid; 
}

intiateGrid(2); 
grid[0,0] = 5; 
let newGrid = intiateGrid(3);
  
console.log(grid);
```

We changed grid without having that as a goal, all we wanted to do was to assign a new grid to another variable! This is why working with code that has side effects like this is considered dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your question, but this:

> For example, `let p = grid[0][0]`, I would then want to be able to move it to grid[1][0], grid[1][5], etc.

makes it seem as if you want to create some sort of "pointer" to a position within the two-dimensional array structure. There's no real way to accomplish that with a simple value. One approach would be to use an object:

```
let p = { x: 0, y: 0 };
```

Then you could create functions to use such an object to return a grid cell:

```
function getCell(pointer) {
  return grid[pointer.x][pointer.y];
}

function setCell(pointer, value) {
  grid[pointer.x][pointer.y] = value;
}
```

You cannot ultimately get around the need to use two separate numbers to index explicitly into the 2-dimensional structure other than to hide that inside functions like those two examples.

Comment: This definitely helps the second part of this project, but would I then need to change `grid` to an array of objects or is using an array still acceptable?

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman an array is fine. The basic issue is that while the thing you want to do makes sense logically, there's just no direct way of doing that in JavaScript. It would be possible to create fancier versions of my suggestion of course.

Comment: Wait, so there is no way of incrementing `p` along the x axis so it becomes `x: 1, y:0`  which is then reflected in the grid?